# onclick event to get email then mailto in html

Tags: html, json, web, onclick, mailto

Hello I am pretty new in web development, I want to set up an hyperlink that if user click, it extract certain email address from a json file, then apply this address to the mailto method.
my code is like this

```
<div class="vipSpanTechnology spriteHover" ng-repeat="vip in vips">
    <p> <b>{{vip.name}}</b>
        <br>{{vip.title}}<br>                   
        <a sprite-class-indexed="email-addresses-" href="mailto:" onClick="this.href='mailto:{{vip.email}}'" target="_blank"></a>
    </p>
</div>
```

but it can only apply mailto with the string {{vip.email}}, not the email string stored in {{vip.email}}. Is there any idea? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
onclick='this.href="'{{ vip.email }}'";'
```